# Write # in yaml (in the string)

Tags: syntax, internationalization, tags, comments, yaml

I'm new using yml files (for translations in my framework).

I'm trying to add a "#" inside the translation (will be a twitter share... blabla).

Is this possible, because the file translate it like a comment...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Just put the value inside single or double quotes and it won't be treated like a comment.  Something like:

```
en:
  twitter:
    share: "#hashtag"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: And then, because of course your original string had quotes in it, escape those quotes with backslash. And use a double-backslash to escape that. `val: "string #hashtag \"quotes\" \\\\windows\\unc\\share"`

Comment: It should be noted that `share: some text "#hashtag"` won't work.