# Value with # in YML file

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

```
MainNode:
 SubnodeOne: #Value
 SubnodeTwo: someValue
```

I want add a value as above for the SubnodeOne. But in yaml # makes the value a comment. So i can not set a value with #. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write # in yaml (in the string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711444/write-in-yaml-in-the-string)

Answer (score 0):

Quote it:

```
MainNode:
 SubnodeOne: "#Value"
 SubnodeTwo: someValue
```